# Power means inequality

Tags: inequality

Rummaging through old notebooks from high school I found the following inequality. Let $x, y, z$ and $t$ be positive numbers such that $x+y+z+t=1$. Then the following inequality holds:
$$
1 < \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + t^4} - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2)}{\sqrt[3]{x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + t^4} - \sqrt{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + t^3}}<4
$$

While the left part is almost obvious from the power means monotonicity, the right part escapes me. I verified it with Mathematica and it seems correct. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Also asked at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107551/an-inequality-involving-sums-of-powers) now.

Comment: Great title, philosophically speaking. Now if I could only figure out what the quetsion has to do with it...

Comment: The title comes from my (completely unfounded) belief that the proof of this inequality will come from examining some properties of the power means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the proof at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107551/an-inequality-involving-sums-of-powers/107594